# vim+ Latex Suite, Can the compile window be in a sub-window?

Tags: vim, vim-latex

I am using vim+latex suite. When \ll, the compile window takes the whole area of the vim window, no matter how many other subwindow I have opened.

Can the compile process just be shown in another sub-window?

Thanks.

Comment: Depending on your system, you might be able to use `tmux`, `screen`, or another terminal window for your compilation while writing in Vim.